# Can I ask a question about movie demographics data?

Tags: support, scope

An [article](http://variety.com/2015/film/news/avengers-age-of-ultron-box-office-opening-1201486323/) discusses the demographics for *Avengers: Age of Ultron* during opening weekend:

> The film played broadly across demographic categories. Roughly 59% of the audience was male, 41% was 25 years and older, 12% were teenagers and 22% were families.

Would a question asking how they got that data be on-topic for Movies.SE?

Comment: I think that would be perfectly on topic.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why it would be off topic.

We have questions about [content-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-rating) systems and about [box-office](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/box-office) information.

This is definitely a valid, answerable question about film.

That being said, feel free to do some additional research before kicking it over to us. Well-researched questions are always appreciated.